# CrudRepository,Can't get the correct result query with And Between

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

I am having trouble using spring-boot CrudRepository，What I want to do is to look up the data for a period of time

I make a query by this and result is ok

```
List<T> findByTimestampAfter(@Param("timestamp") Date start)
```

This is also ok

```
List<T> findByTimestampBefore(@Param("timestamp") Date end)
```

But I tried the following three methods do not work:

```
List<T> findByTimestampBetween(@Param("timestamp") Date start,@Param("timestamp") Date end)

List<T> findByTimestampAfterAndTimestampBefore(@Param("timestamp") Date start,@Param("timestamp") Date end)

List<T> findByTimestampGreaterThanEqualAndTimestampLessThanEqual(@Param("timestamp") Date start,@Param("timestamp") Date end)
```

**What I want to get is more than 100 data in the time frame, but there is only one which timestamp euqal end**

And i try execute this sql statementselect:

```
select  * from exchange where timestamp > "2018-01-02 17:30:00" AND timestamp < "2018-01-02 17:48:00";
```

i can see the more than 100 data.

I think I can not solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

See the query executing from the jpa automatically.If you just use proper debugging logger .Also tell the proper result achieved from above three methods.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `between` is not supported inside method name. You should define your custom query, for example:

```
@Query("select * from exchange where timestamp > ?1 AND timestamp < ?2")
Object[] findByTimeCustomQuery(Date dFrom, Date dTo);
```